# How to get rid of awful useless macros

Tags: c, sed, preprocessor

I've got a quite large C and C++ code (~200k loc) which makes extensive use of awful macros:

```
/* ... */
#define PRIVATE static
#define BEGIN           {
#define END             }
/* ... */
#define WHILE(e)        while (e) {
#define DO /* yep, it's empty */
#define ENDWHILE        }
/* and it goes on and on, for every keyword of the language */
```

Here is the thing, I want to get rid of that stupid header, clean the code, and indent it properly.

At first, I wanted to use a simple `sed` to replace all those macros, but it seems it's not that simple.

The case of the `WHILE` is quite problematic (and it is the same for other statements). I can't juste replace `WHILE` by `while`, because the opening curly bracket will be missing. And of course, as the `DO` macro doesn't do anything, it's not always present in the code. Hence, replacing `DO` by `{` won't do the trick.

I can't use the endline either, because conditions are often split into multiple lines:

```
WHILE (clsr_calibragedf_tabdisque.tab_disque[indice_disque].tab_date[indice_date] NE
                   clsr_calibragedf_tabdate [indice].date) DO
                indice ++;
            ENDWHILE
```

The best solution I can think of would be a C preprocessor which could replace only thoses specific macros, and not expand the `#include` directives, or the others macros. But I can't find anything like that.

Any idea?

Comment: I think sed will be fine, but you need a proper regular expression to match *including* the expression and opening brace. Then just replace with `while` and the RE matching text (which will include, thus carry over, the opening brace).

Comment: The problem is the multiple parenthesis the expression can contain.

Comment: I think you can get around that since you know there must be a single opening brace after the parenthesis. E.g. an RE like `'\(.+\) \{'` would probably work in practice.

Comment: I would concentrate on defense: first make sure you have tests that make you feel safe, then start replacing the macros one-by one.  Changing "DO" to "{" is actually a good start, the compiler will *catch* the missing DO's for you, and you can replace them yourself.  Then you replace the WHILE etc.

Comment: Of course, the step by step method was part of my plan, to make sure everything works as before a the end of the cleaning process.

Answer (score 7):

Yuck! How about:

1. Run your program through some `perl` to comment out `#include` directives in a distinctive way (e.g. `/*FIXSTUFF #include <blah.h> FIXSTUFF*/`). You might want to comment out other preprocessor stuff (e.g. `#define`) in a similar way.
2. Check each file `#include`s the definition of the weird macros (only).
3. Now run `gcc -E` on each file, which will preprocess the macros.
4. Reverse step 1.
5. Run `indent` for good measure.

Note, C Preprocessing does the following (stolen from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor)):

1. Trigraph replacement: The preprocessor replaces trigraph sequences with the characters they represent.
2. Line splicing: Physical source lines that are continued with escaped newline sequences are spliced to form logical lines.
3. Tokenization: The preprocessor breaks the result into preprocessing tokens and whitespace. It replaces comments with whitespace.
4. Macro expansion and directive handling: Preprocessing directive lines, including file inclusion and conditional compilation, are executed. The preprocessor simultaneously expands macros and, in the 1999 version of the C standard, handles _Pragma operators.

You are thus in theory going to lose trigraphs in the source code (some would suggest this is a bonus), and potentially alter line splicing (fixed at step 5 with `indent`). You will need to protect any other preprocessor directices as per step (1).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The [Eclipse IDE](https://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) has some great tools for searching and replacing. You could import your code there, and then use the *File Search* tool. You can use it like this:

1. open it up with `Ctrl + H` (or `Search > File...` in the context menu) to search for all occurences of one of your macros
2. click on `Replace...` to open the replacement window and can choose the replacement
3. click on `Preview >` to review all replacements and apply them with `OK`

#### Using regular expressions

For more complex cases, you can use the *Regular expression* tick in the file search view. For example, here is how you can apply this to your WHILE-ENDWHILE-macro:

1. Search for the regex (see reverse lookup for how it works):

   `WHILE(((?!ENDWHILE).|\s)+)ENDWHILE`
2. Insert the replacement `while(\1)`
3. Review the result in the preview page and apply it

Comment: Like I said, replacing "WHILE" by "while" isn't enough.

Comment: Sure, but you can use the *Regular expression* tick in the search field, and then, when replacing, you can use for example *\1* for the value of the first group, *\2* for the second and so on.

Comment: For example, you have the text `This is a beautiful text`, then you can use the regular expression `This is a ([a-zA-Z]+) text` and in the replacement field use `The text was \1`. The result would be `The text was beautiful`.

Comment: Take a look at the example I gave with the multi line WHILE condition, a find/replace isn't enough

Comment: You can create a regular expression for this, you must create one that finds the occurence of anything starting with `WHILE` and ending with `ENDWHILE` and then simply use the replacement `while(\1)`. Then you even have a preview to check if everything was fine there.

Comment: I added the example on how to do it in the answer, hope it helps. :)